How can I compute amountOut?
I can't compute amountOut and get poolKeys for a swap on raydium. Can someone provide a simple example?
  const amountOut = Liquidity.computeAmountOut({
    poolKeys,
    poolInfo,
    amountIn: amountIn,
    currencyOut: this.config.quoteToken,
    slippage,
  }).amountOut;


Up we need help please

https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/15841/how-to-get-amountout-of-a-swap-on-raydium-solana-please
